# Can I see my Harmony before the end of the game in As Far As The Eye?

Tags: as-far-as-the-eye

In As Far As The Eye there is a resource called **Harmony** which impacts the number of minor vagaries.

When winning a game the value is displayed

[image]

I'd like to see it in-game to know how bad the world has been destroyed.
Is it possible or is Harmony truly hidden ?